# how to verify a JWT token with empty payload

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token

Below code works fine when payload is present .But when payload is empty i get error as
**"Body/Payload is missing"**
How to fix the error.I am able to verify the token on jwt.io website
Sample JWT token with "" empty payload

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9..eoZhroqrfGu9P5dEeCceFZ8oG3XUlvOS6vKUSp4dwO86p_DDy_blNSvez3QLQBgxmaL_VRXxPNXBpDKIc3FHa9vmbEligItW5mrtamAlt_NrvSuXBYMhJrUkc6GHamVHYF4-g7PrrgycevIFCmoquZY1bUr0gb0Foo50oPhcA5vO2DMso6PuevdFQ2NBH5uSdHteRfClR1KjxUzguNm4a0FafMKj5oM6d1p4HVanUMyR8LJMduqrEuSfTPXxV_hVz2pYqxibQ3u9U2_BbHLt0Phmq8ENG_arxd0nY4VDnUq8WpydhR2Q8ilHEOQjG4tvkLrdstgwWJaMLJtzr-xAFw

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
public static boolean verify(String jwtToken, String publicKeyString) throws Exception {
     
           
        try {
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyString
                    .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", ""));

            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);


            Jws<Claims> claimsJws = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(publicKey)
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like an XY problem to me, why would you absolutely need an empty payload? This shouldn't be because of oauth from what I know.. passing a simple string like "myPayload" should be a valid solution. We need more details if you want relevant help, like for example, which line causes this error in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The token you share is a JWS i.e. a digitally signed JWT.
The digital signature is computed using the the header and the payload.

Detached payload is not common, but still valid. It is mentioned in the [Appendix F of the RFC7515](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#appendix-F).
This is very useful when the payload size is too big for being transmitted over a HTTP request. It sent by other means that are out of scope of the specification.
This behaviour is more useful when combined with the [RFC7797](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7797) where the Base64 URl Safe encoding is skipped.

But in all cases, all parts (header, payload and signature) shall be provided for signature validation.

That is why we do not understand what you expect by stripping the payload. It is mandatory to provide these parts (untampered) for validating the token otherwise it will undoubtedly fail.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the sample token that you've provided is not a JWT: a JWT defines the payload as JSON. In your case the payload is empty, which may be considered as invalid JSON. Hence a JWT routine may not be able to verify the token.

However, what you can do is treat it as a JWS (JSON Web Signature), which is a superset of JWT and can embed opaque content such as the payload that you've provided here. Apparently jwt.io is able to verify JWS as well as JWT.

A quick search reveals that io.jsonwebtoken does seem to have support for "raw" JWS as well as JWTS, see e.g.: https://javadoc.io/doc/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.9.1/io/jsonwebtoken/Jws.html

> B - the type of the JWS body contents, either a String or a Claims
> instance.

so you should/may be able to use the JWS class